In the if statement I would like the first parameter to do nothing
IF inOverseasFlag = 'YES' THEN
    ELSE 
     SELECT MPMD06X, -- Account Name
                  MPMD04X, -- Sort Code
                  MPMD05X, -- Account Number              
                  MPMD09X  -- BS Rollno
      INTO vBankAccountName, vBankSortCode, vBankAccountNumber, vBsRollNo
      FROM MP_Mandate
      WHERE BGroup = inBGroup
      AND Mandate = inMandate;
    END IF;


I think you want IF inOverseasFlag != 'YES' THEN SELECT MPMD06X, etc. != means does not equal. Documentation: Comparison Conditions. "If A Then X Else Y" is logically the same as "If !A Then Y Else X" where A is a binary condition.

@AndrewMorton unless inOverseasFlag can be null.

@WilliamRobertson That's why I wrote "where A is a binary condition."

"Do nothing" in pl/sql can be achieved with the NULL statement. The NULL statement is a ''no-op" (no operation)—it only passes control to the next statement. Sometimes it can be useful to write an branch in an IF ELSEIF statement that doesn't do anything but makes code more understandable. It also comes in handy when writing new code as a temporary placeholder.
Example:
DECLARE
  l_var VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  IF (l_var = 'FOO') THEN
    -- no action needed for FOO, but showing it here anyway.
    NULL;
  ELSIF (l_var = 'BAR') THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('BAR');
  END IF;
END;

For reference, here is the documentation
